# How Get Biggest area In contour OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencart2.x

I would know if there is any method to get the biggest area INSIDE contour !
like the image under!
Thank's a lot.
[image: Biggest area]

Comment: Does it have to be an upright rectangle? Or can it be at an angle?

Comment: Yes it have to be a rectangle !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a good idea to find this rectangle ant it work very well.
For any one interested : [here the link (Thank's Daniel)](http://d3plus.org/blog/behind-the-scenes/2014/07/08/largest-rect/) .